# Passing a delegate within a delegate (happened by intellisense)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, events, delegates, arguments

good afternoon.
I was working on my video game in unity creating some events and then when I pressed tab the IDE auto completed this:

'''

```
public delegate void Battle();
public static event Battle OnBattle_Started;
public static event Battle OnBattle_Completed;

public delegate void Battle_Start(Battle battle);
```

'''

the delegate void Battle_Start has delegate Battle passed in as an argument.
what does this mean and what does this do??
(does this mean that Battle_Start requires an invoke of either OnBattle_Started or OnBattle_Completed)

Comment: Battle_Start is a delegate that takes the Battle delegate, and Battle is a Void delegate. What is the question for you?

Comment: oh, so this is just passing around delegates and not the activation of events??

Comment: so if i had a delegate that had like 3 parameters and wanted another delegate to require all of that plus 2 more parameters, then instead of making a new delegate that has a total of 5 parameters i can just pass the first delegate with the new two parameters?? okay, i was just shocked when the IDE did this. i never thought of doing this with an delegate so it took me by surprise